# searching in a django models of vectors with a custom function

Tags: python, django, django-models

im using django for a face recogntion app and i need to save face descriptor in djangomodel and then retreive them and compare with the vectors of a new image and get the model in the database that have the nearest distance with the new vectore.

**so in short**

- i have a model of persons
- each model have a *textfield* that represent a *vector*
- i have a *function compare(vec1,vec2)* that take two vectors as
  strings and return the distance between them
- i have a new vector (not in the database)
- i need to apply the compare  function on the model and retrieve the
  person that his vector field have the minimum distance with the new
  vector

Comment: This logic should probably be implemented using a custom queryset or manager : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: @Raynaud  i tried reading about managers but couldnt find how to do it can you tell me how to do it if this not too much for you.

Comment: I'm going to write a more comprehensive response with pseudo code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first, you probably want a custom Queryset and not a custom Manager. Let me briefly explain the difference between the two: In both cases the objective is to allow to do something like `Person.objects.my_custom_method()` but if you do a custom Manager you can only use it directly, while if you use a custom QuerySet you'll be able to use chained with other Queryset methods that return a queryset, for example `Person.objects.filter(country__iso_code2='US').my_custom_method()` which my be helpful for your application.

For your problem, you want a custom method allowing you to get all the users vectors, compare those to a given vector and return the closest, according to your distance, so the method should take as an argument the vector you want to compare, and return the instance of Person that is the closest. I'll write something like this:

Create a managers.py field, where you'll write your custom queryset and manager:

```
class PersonQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def get_closest_user(self, input_vector):
        for person in self:    
            # this is a loop over every person in your database unless the qs is filtered
            current_dist = compare(input_vector, person.vector)
            if best_dist is None or current_dist < best_dist:
                best_dist = current_dist
                closest_person = person
        return closest_person, best_dist

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PersonQuerySet(self.model, using=self.db)

    def get_closest_user(self, input_vector):
        return self.get_queryset().get_closest_user(input_vector)
```

Modify the models.py like this, so that Django uses the custom Manager you defined

```
from .managers import PersonManager
class Person(models.Model):
    # Manager
    objects = PersonManager()
    (...) # your code for the class Person.
```

Once you've done those modifications, when you'll need to get the person, you'll be able to simply call `Person.objects.get_closest_user(input_vector)`

Note that given your use case, you might find yourself in a situation where this is very computationally intensive, so you might want to use a more complexe method to be able to filter your request instead of having to compute the distance on the whole database. A good way to limit the computation would be to use a [Locality-sensitive_hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing). Directly modify the queryset to implement this kind of logic.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed response i'll try it tommorow and see (can't try it in my pc) .
But for LHS won't I need to calculate the hash code for every vector ? isn't it the same in term of computation? unless i can  use another model in my queryset so that i will save the hashes in a separate model (as a hash tabe) and refer it with a one-to-many relation. sorry if the question is a little weird because i'm new o django i know only the basics for creating a simple website.

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS is not for storing the vectors, you need to use either elastic search or opensearch to store the vectors and perform the similarity checks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).